# Karate - how to run multiple scenarios in a single feature file parallely?

Tags: karate

I Have 4 scenarios in my feature file, and I want all my four scenarios to run in parallel, here is my feature file,

```
  Feature:

  Background:
    * def Json = Java.type('Json')
    * def dq = new Json()
    * def result = dq.makeJson('0')
    * def result1 = dq.makeJson('110')
    * def result2 = dq.makeJson('220')
    * def result3 = dq.makeJson('330')

    Scenario Outline: id : <id>
    * def ds_hotel_id = '<id>'
    *  print ds_hotel_id

    Examples:
    |result|

  Scenario Outline: id : <id>

    * def ds_hotel_id = '<id>'
    *  print ds_hotel_id

    Examples:
      |result1|

  Scenario Outline: id : <id>
    * def ds_hotel_id = '<id>'
    *  print ds_hotel_id


    Examples:
      |result2|

  Scenario Outline: id : <id>

    * def ds_hotel_id = '<id>'
    *  print ds_hotel_id

    Examples:
      |result3|
```

I am running it by this command line,

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber-html " -Dtest=dsRunner.java
```

What should I do, so that it can make it run all the scenarios simultaneously so that I can decrease the compilation time for my project? :)

Comment: I didnt get what do you want to ask...

Comment: Varun: clearly you haven't taken the time to read the documentation. I will not explain this here, but `--plugin html:target/cucumber-html` is wrong and not supported, and if `dsRunner.java` is using the `@RunWith(Karate.class)` annotation it will NOT run in parallel. please read the docs instead of asking un-necessary questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 0.9.0, scenarios are launched in parallel, unless specified otherwise with `@parallel=false`

If your features are running in parallel, then your scenarios will.
You should switch to 0.9.1 if that is not already the case.